# Check if zip code belongs to country

Tags: php, validation, e-commerce, zipcode

We've got a problem with an online shop that is available in many countries. 
People type in their - for example - German address and choose a different country from dropdown to get lower tax rates (tax rates calculated by country).
We would need a validator to check if the given zip belongs to the chosen country.
Is there any ready to use possibility to do so?

Comment: Here are many libraries: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=zip+to+country

Comment: i couldn't find a lib there that does what i'm looking for. i need to check if GIVEN ZIP belongs to GIVEN COUNRY from a php e-commerce application

Comment: your shipping service should do address validation for delivery.

Comment: the online shop deals with digital goods. and on delivery it would be too late when the invoice was already created and paid. i must directly validate after the customer entered the  data.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is some kind of address validation for international zip codes.

As a solution, you could use the International Address Validator API made by SmartyStreets. Here is the [demo page](https://smartystreets.com/demo/api#international-street) to see how it might look.

Here is the [documentation page](https://smartystreets.com/docs/international-street-api) with instructions on how to use the API.

You should go to the demo page linked above and see if your data will work well with it. You can enter an address in "free form" all on one line by changing one of the field dropdowns to "freeform". Or, you can enter the address information one field at a time, with "country" on one line, "postal code" on another line, and street address on "address1".

Also, remember, it is hard to make an API that works for multiple countries. Addresses can have very different formats in other countries. Because of that, I don't think you can search for a zip code alone. You have to search for an address with a zip code, and the validator can then tell you if the zip code is in that country.

---

Full disclosure: I work for SmartyStreets.